# Cant use JSONP to call wikipedia API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, jsonp, wikipedia

I am not sure if I am really using JSONP to call the wikipedia API. I'm trying to use this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyeqy/2/) to call the two wikipedia query below. It works on item number 1 but not item number 2.

```
1. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=India&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&callback=?

2. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allpages&gaplimit=3&gapfrom=Ba&prop=links%7Ccategories&callback=?
```

I've checked the javascript console and got this error message.

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allpages&gaplimit…tegories&callback=jQuery17208101096539758146_1453227700616&_=1453227700630' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Comment: Did you even open the [url](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allpages&gaplimit=3&gapfrom=Ba&prop=links%7Ccategories&callback=?) yourself, and read what it says at the top.

Comment: Yes, but I was not aware that im just opening an HTML. My mind got muddled with all this searching about jsonp. haha! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see if you actually go to that URL, it's serving HTML, not JSON.

You need to add `&format=json`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not saw that.